# the content cannot be displayed in a frame sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

I am trying to open a modal pop up using the following javascript

```
 if (this.Context != null && !this.Context.Items.Contains(SPRequestModule.AllowFramingFlag)) {

            this.Context.Items.Add(SPRequestModule.AllowFramingFlag, "1");
        }



            var options = { url: "https://eeeee/Lists/ProjectLibrary/NewForm.aspx", width: 400, height: 300 };
    enter code here
            SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);`
```

I have added the site to the trusted sites zone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure the X-Frame-Options response header

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Hi NathanOliver, I am newbie. I'll make it a comment next time.